# Join table where field value in one table is a column name in another table

Tags: php, sql

I have two tables service_category and category_mapping. I want to display categories and number of companies listed in particular category

```
Table service_category:

id    cattegory          mappingid
1     Construction          cc
2     InteriorDesign        idn
3     TechnicalWork         tw
4     MarineConstruction    mc

Table category_mapping:

id    companyid        cc    idn    tw   mc
1         4            Y      Y     N    N
2         5            N      Y     N    Y
3         6            N      N     N    Y
4         7            Y      N     N    N
```

something like this

```
SELECT  sc.*,(select count(*) from category_mapping where `XYZ`='Y' ) as companycount  FROM  service_category as sc
```

can anybody help me?

Comment: Is the name of columns known upfront?

Comment: column name.   I want to find number of companies in each category

Comment: name of the column is dynamic. not known upfront ( cc and idn is dynamic)

Comment: Did You mean to say that your company id may increase and then columns in category_mapping will go increase or change..

Comment: @anwaar_hell  - Yes you are correct.There will be one row in category_mapping for each company

Comment: Can you add some more rows to both table ....so that we can go in right direction.

Comment: added two more rows in both tables

Answer (score 0):

This will help for only mentioned categories..mention if there are nay more categories..

```
select id, cattegory ,mappingid ,(select  count(*) from category_mapping  where cc='Y') as count
from 
service_category
where mappingid='CC'
union 
select id, cattegory ,mappingid ,(select  count(*) from category_mapping  where idn='Y') as count
from 
service_category
where mappingid='idn'
```